# Move an item in a RecyclerView to a specific position

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I am using a RecyclerView to populate data that are fetched in my Room database. When data is fetched or removed from my Room database, the RecyclerView is updated automatically. I have implemented a swipe to delete and undo in my RecyclerView. When i swipe, i delete the item in my Room Database and the RecyclerView gets updated automatically. However, when i click the "Undo" button, i insert the item again in the Room database and the item is shown in the Recyclerview. The problem here is when i restore the item, it gets restored in the last position. I want it to be restore in the position it was deleted, not last.

My code is as below:

fragment.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@id/RecyclerView_fromFragmentToDo_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/Margin_Views_Small"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

adapter.kt

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.lifestyle.ToDo
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.databinding.CustomRecyclerviewListTodoBinding

class ToDoAdapter : ListAdapter<ToDo, ToDoAdapter.ViewHolder>(ToDoDiffCallback()) {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val toDo = getItem(position)
    holder.bind(toDo)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder.from(parent)
}

class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: CustomRecyclerviewListTodoBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind(toDo: ToDo) {
        binding.myToDo = toDo
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = CustomRecyclerviewListTodoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}
}

class ToDoDiffCallback: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ToDo>() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ToDo, newItem: ToDo): Boolean {
    return oldItem.id == newItem.id
}


override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ToDo, newItem: ToDo): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
}

}
```

viewmodel.kt

```
import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.lifestyle.ToDo
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.operations.Filter
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.core.operations.ToDoOperations
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.database.LifestyleDatabase
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.ui.enums.ToggleButtonStates
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class ToDoViewModel(
    val database: LifestyleDatabase,
    application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private var _viewModelJob = Job()

private val _uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + _viewModelJob)

//Current state of the toggle button (Current button checked)
var currentToggleButtonState = ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_ACTIVE

//Fetch all to dos from database
private var _toDos = ToDoOperations.getAllOffline(database)
val toDosMediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<List<ToDo>>()

init {
    //Update the list of the recyclerview on INIT
    updateList(currentToggleButtonState)
}


/**
 * Public functions that are accessible from the outside
 **/

fun updateList(toggleButton: ToggleButtonStates) {
    toDosMediatorLiveData.removeSource(_toDos)

    when(toggleButton){
        ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_ALL ->{
            currentToggleButtonState = ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_ALL

            toDosMediatorLiveData.addSource(_toDos){
                toDosMediatorLiveData.value = it
            }
        }

        ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_ACTIVE ->{
            currentToggleButtonState = ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_ACTIVE

            toDosMediatorLiveData.addSource(_toDos){
                toDosMediatorLiveData.value = Filter<ToDo>(it).getActive()
            }
        }
        ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_COMPLETE ->{
            currentToggleButtonState = ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_COMPLETE

            toDosMediatorLiveData.addSource(_toDos){
                toDosMediatorLiveData.value = Filter<ToDo>(it).getCompleted()
            }
        }
    }
}

fun insertItem(toDo: ToDo) {
    _uiScope.launch {
        insert(toDo)
    }
}

fun markAsDeleted(toDo: ToDo) {
    _uiScope.launch {
        remove(toDo)
    }
}

fun markItem(toDo: ToDo){
    if(toDo.dateCompleted == null){
        markAsCompleted(toDo)
    }else{
        markAsIncomplete(toDo)
    }
}


/**
 * Private functions for internal use ONLY
 **/

private fun markAsCompleted(newToDo: ToDo) {
    _uiScope.launch {
        newToDo.markAsComplete()
        update(newToDo)
    }
}

private fun markAsIncomplete(newToDo: ToDo) {
    _uiScope.launch {
        newToDo.markAsIncomplete()
        update(newToDo)
    }
}

private suspend fun insert(toDo: ToDo) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        toDo.add(database)
    }
}

private suspend fun remove(toDo: ToDo) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        toDo.delete(database)
    }
}

private suspend fun update(newToDo: ToDo) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        newToDo.update(database)
    }
}

/**
 * Overridden functions
 **/
override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()

    //Clear the view model job when user leave
    _viewModelJob.cancel()
}
}
```

fragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.R
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.ui.Utils.toast
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.database.LifestyleDatabase
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.databinding.FragmentToDoBinding
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.ui.Utils.action
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.ui.Utils.snackBar
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.ui.Utils.snackBarWithAction
import com.th3pl4gu3.lifestyle.ui.enums.ToggleButtonStates
import java.util.*

class FragmentToDo : Fragment() {

private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentToDoBinding
private lateinit var mToDoViewModel: ToDoViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    //Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_to_do, container, false)

    //Configures the screen views (Eg. Title, appearance of top bar etc...)
    configureScreenAppearance()

    //Get the activity's application
    val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

    //Fetch the database
    val dataSource = LifestyleDatabase.getInstance(application)

    //Instantiate the view model factory
    val viewModelFactory = ToDoViewModelFactory(dataSource, application)

    //Instantiate the view model of this fragment
    mToDoViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ToDoViewModel::class.java)

    //Bind view model
    mBinding.toDoViewModel = mToDoViewModel

    //Instantiate the lifecycle owner
    mBinding.lifecycleOwner = this

    //RecyclerView's configuration
    val adapter = ToDoAdapter()
    mBinding.RecyclerViewFromFragmentToDoMain.adapter = adapter

    mToDoViewModel.toDosMediatorLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        it.let { x ->

            //Update the UI and determine whether recyclerview should be visible or not
            updateUI(x.isNotEmpty())

            adapter.submitList(x)
        }
    })

    //Swipe configurations
    val swipeHandler = object : ToDoSwipeToCallback(requireContext()) {
        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {

            val swipedToDo = (mBinding.RecyclerViewFromFragmentToDoMain.adapter as ToDoAdapter).currentList[viewHolder.adapterPosition]
            val fab = requireActivity().findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.FAB_fromHomeActivity_BottomAppBarAttached)
            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition

            when(direction){
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT -> {
                    mToDoViewModel.markItem(swipedToDo)
                }

                ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT -> {
                    mToDoViewModel.markAsDeleted(swipedToDo)

                    //Show Snackbar with 'Undo' action
                    requireActivity().findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).snackBarWithAction(getString(R.string.Message_Exception_fromFragmentLifeStyleItems_ErrorWhileSwiping, swipedToDo.title), anchorView = fab){
                            action("Undo"){
                                mToDoViewModel.insertItem(swipedToDo)
                                //Restore Item
                            }
                        }
                }

                else ->{
                    requireContext().toast(getString(R.string.Message_Exception_fromFragmentLifeStyleItems_ErrorWhileSwiping))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mBinding.RecyclerViewFromFragmentToDoMain)

    return mBinding.root
}


/**
 * Private functions for internal use ONLY
 **/

private fun updateUI(recyclerViewVisible: Boolean){
    if(recyclerViewVisible){
        mBinding.RecyclerViewFromFragmentToDoMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        mBinding.EmptyViewForRecyclerView.visibility = View.GONE
    }else{
        if(mToDoViewModel.currentToggleButtonState == ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_COMPLETE){
            mBinding.TextViewFromFragmentToDoEmptyView.text = getString(R.string.TextView_fromToDoFragment_Message_EmptyList_Completed)
        }else if(mToDoViewModel.currentToggleButtonState == ToggleButtonStates.BUTTON_ACTIVE){
            mBinding.TextViewFromFragmentToDoEmptyView.text = getString(R.string.TextView_fromToDoFragment_Message_EmptyList_Active)
        }

        mBinding.RecyclerViewFromFragmentToDoMain.visibility = View.GONE
        mBinding.EmptyViewForRecyclerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }
}

private fun configureScreenAppearance(){
    //Set title of fragment
    val screenTitle = requireActivity().findViewById<TextView>(R.id.TextView_fromHomeActivity_Screen_Title)
    screenTitle.text = getString(R.string.TextView_fromFragmentInHomeActivity_ScreenTitle_ToDo)

    //Show Top Bar
    val topBar = requireActivity().findViewById<RelativeLayout>(R.id.RelativeLayout_fromHomeActivity_TopBar)
    topBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    //Show Fab
    val fab = requireActivity().findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.FAB_fromHomeActivity_BottomAppBarAttached)
    fab.show()
}
}
```

I need to restore the item here:

```
ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT -> {
                    mToDoViewModel.markAsDeleted(swipedToDo)

                    //Show Snackbar with 'Undo' action
                    requireActivity().findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).snackBarWithAction(getString(R.string.Message_Exception_fromFragmentLifeStyleItems_ErrorWhileSwiping, swipedToDo.title), anchorView = fab){
                            action("Undo"){
                                mToDoViewModel.insertItem(swipedToDo)
                                //Restore Item
                            }
                        }
                }
```

I've tried fetching the list and then do list.add(position, item) but it doesn't work. Can someone please help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If list.add didn't work then I would suggest a different approach when you swipe to delete don't delete the item. Add another column `isDeleted` in your model and change room query to fetch all rows in which `isDeleted` is false.

```
select * from table where isDeleted = 0
```

Then when swipe to delete update the row to set `isDeleted` true and when you undo just set `isDeleted` to false. You can delete the row at later point when you're sure that there'll be no undo required.

Answer (score 0):

Update your insert function in viewmodel.kt file as follows

```
private suspend fun insert(toDo: ToDo) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        toDo.add(index, database)
    }
}
```

Here index is an integer which indicates the position that you want to insert the new item. And notify recyclerview adapter if necessary as follows

```
//Show Snackbar with 'Undo' action
requireActivity().findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).snackBarWithAction(getString(R.string.Message_Exception_fromFragmentLifeStyleItems_ErrorWhileSwiping, swipedToDo.title), anchorView = fab){
    action("Undo"){
        mToDoViewModel.insertItem(swipedToDo)
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(index)
        //Restore Item
    }
}
```

Comment: The add function in my ViewModel will add the item in my Room Database, not to an array. How should i add the index ?

Comment: What about putting an 'ORDER BY' query in SQL statement of your DAO?